# Where can I find the complete dataset of AADHAR?

Tags: dataset

I am planning to analyze the dataset for AADHAR. The website (https://data.uidai.gov.in/uiddatacatalog/dataCatalogHome.do) only gives the most recently updated values.

Is the entire dataset through the months archived somewhere?